# Angular material sorting don't wanna cooperate with my app

Tags: angular, typescript, list, sorting, angular-material

I trying to make sorting in my app but ... list showing up but no sorting.
I think the source is at my `@Input() data: string[];`.
In constructor i need to do something like that:

```
sortedData: string[];
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.sortedData = this.data.slice();
}
```

There i getting error about undefined - slice can be done on undefined type. I tried to do some if's around it, but after it my list appears without sorting functionality.

Comment: move this.sortedData = this.data.slice(); to ngOnInit(){}

Comment: constructor is called before @Input() data arrives to your compnent, so this.data is undefined

Comment: Problem was solved but sorting still not works ... hmm

Comment: could you show your data?

Comment: Ok, i saw i assing wrong data in table, now its ok. Thanks!

Comment: @BartoszTermena is right, that why @Yamdi should write code in the `ngOnInit` function.